# Trying to interest Wolfram in correcting an error in a built-in function

Tags: wolfram-physics

There is a Mathematica function that produces a nonsense, non-physical output and I haven't managed to interest Wolfram in the problem. The function is:

```
    PlanckRadiationLaw[t,λ]
```

The function accepts data in the form of a temperature (*t*) and wavelength (*λ*) and returns a value with typical units of:

```
    W/(m^3 sr)
```

This is incorrect. If the wavelength *λ* of the impinging radiation is in units for example, of *μm* and the area through which the radiation acts is in *m^2*, the answer should be returned as:

```
    W/(m^2 sr μm)
```

The two length based measures in units of *m* and *μm* should not be combined, one is an area, the other a wavelength. Combining them is nonsense. A Wolfram engineer pointed me to a wiki entry to support the argument that their function returns the correct value, however, the wiki article is also incorrect.

The problem perhaps points to a deeper issue in the way that Mathematica handles units, where like measures are combined. The Planck Radiation Law however, is one example of where this procedure falls down.

Keen to correspond with an open-minded Wolfram engineer who might frequent these pages.

Comment: Even if you are technically correct, I suspect that what you are asking for is impossible within Mathematica's units system, since (I guess) it is implemented on the assumption that each "Length" dimension has the same unit.

Comment: I think it is completely o.k. to express everything in basic SI units. It makes subsequent calculations simpler.

Comment: I agree with @DanielHuber. David, please learn more about the proper use of units before lecturing others.

Comment: @Roman - sorry, do you not understand the issue? I was pointing out a nonsense result, not lecturing anyone. The result is physically incorrect.

Comment: @DanielHuber I think this goes far beyond simplifying calculations. Dimensional analysis is a very powerful tool and great insights can come from noticing that quantities have matching units (think, e.g., of thermodynamics and the insights connecting the different forms of energy). A meter is a meter is a meter: this insight is deeper than it looks. Take it away, and physics (theory and practice of measurement) falls apart.

Comment: @DavidH. you seem to think that meters times square meters should not be written as cube meters, if the underlying formula refers to a distance and an area. I’m saying that you’re very wrong and that m*m^2=m^3, always, and that it has to be this way to do physics properly.

Comment: @Roman you have now demonstrated that you have no idea what the issue is, which is the return of a non-physical result. A journal would reject a paper with such a result given.

Comment: @Mikado I wonder that too.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a concrete example: input, output, desired output that you would consider correct.

Comment: @Roman - that is all in my post. Apologies for any implied disrespect, not intended. However, the result is nonsense.

Comment: I am trying to find a reference for the claim in this post. No success thus far. Perhaps post a link?

Comment: _"The two length based measures in units of m and μm should not be combined, one is an area, the other a wavelength. Combining them is nonsense."_ So you are saying that the volume of a prism with the base area $B=2 \; \mathrm{m}^2$ and height $h=3\;\mathrm{m}$ is not $V=6\;\mathrm{m}^3$ but $V=6\;\mathrm{m}^2 \cdot \mathrm{m}$?